# How use `Option.get` as an function together with pipe

Tags: scala

Is there a way I could replace the `myOptionGet` function by an build-in Scala function,
but without making the code more verbose...? :)  and with keeping the function chaining with `pipe`.

Replacing by `Option.get` doesn't work as I found out.

```
package playground

import scala.util.chaining.scalaUtilChainingOps

object TEST123 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def myOptionGet[T](x: Option[T]): T = x.get

    Some("abc") pipe
      myOptionGet pipe
      println

    // prints: abc

  }
}
```

Comment: Never use `.get`, compose with `Option`

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complex and unsafe when you can just do `Some("abc").foreach(println)` or even if you just want to be unsafe no need to use `pipe` for the `get` like `Some("abc").get pipe println` - Anyways, you can do this: `Some("abc").pipe(_.get).pipe(println)` or `Some("abc") pipe (_.get) pipe println` if you really really want to make your code to scare people off the language.

Comment: "Never say never... Yeah, yeah, never ever"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code can be made less verbose by using a lambda:

```
Some("abc") pipe
  ((o: Option[String]) => o.get) pipe
  println
```

or even shorter with a placeholder:

```
Some("abc") pipe
  (_.get) pipe
  println
```

However, as @cchantep pointed out in a comment, you should never use `.get` because it's unsafe. You should either keep the `Option` type to denote that the value might not exist (this is the safe variant of Java's null pointer technique), or alternatively, if you have a sensible default value, use `myOption.getOrElse("N/A")`.